# Proving $\int_0^1 \frac{(\ln(x))^5}{1+x} \mathrm{d}x = -\frac{31\pi^6}{252}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, closed-form

I would like to show the following identity:

> $$\boxed{
> I := 
> \int_0^1 \dfrac{(\ln(x))^5}{1+x} \mathrm{d}x =
> -\dfrac{31\pi^6}{252}
> }$$

---

Here is what I tried.
The change of variables $u=1/x$ yields
$$I=
\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{(\ln(x))^5}{1+1/u} \dfrac{1}{u^2} \mathrm{d}u =
\int_1^{\infty} \dfrac{(\ln(x))^5}{u^2+u} \mathrm{d}u$$
Then $z=u-1$ gives
$$I = \int_{0}^{\infty} \dfrac{(\ln(z+1))^5}{z^2+3z+2} \mathrm{d}z $$
with $z^2+3z+2=(z+1)(z+2)$.
I wanted to use contour integration like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2027339), but I was not sure how to proceed in this case. Anyway, the computations of the residues (of which "well-chosen" function? Maybe something like [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=residues%20ln(z%2B1)%5E6%20%2F%20(z%5E2%2B3z%2B2))?) seem to be difficult.

I believe that we can generalize to $\frac{(\ln(x))^n}{1+x}$, or maybe even more (e.g. $\frac{(\ln(x))^n}{ax^2+bx+c}$).
Related computations are: [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1976510), [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/316745), [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1854854), [(4)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1186002).

Thank you for your detailed help.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2117032

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

Enforce the substitution $x\to e^{-x}$, expand the resulting denominator in a geometric series of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^ne^{-nx}$, interchange the sum and integral, carryout the integral by either successive IBP or differentiating under the integral, and evaluate the resulting series representation of $\zeta(6)$.

Alternatively, note that

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log^5(x)}{1+x}\,dx=\left. \left(\frac{d^5}{da^5}\int_0^1\frac{x^a}{1+x}\,dx\right)\right|_{a=0}$$

Comment: I was just thinking I recall someone having a nice answer for this problem maybe a year or two ago here, and from your hint I'm willing to bet it was you.

Comment: OK, I think I've managed to solve it:
$$
 \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{(-u)^5}{1+e^{-u}} e^{-u} du =\\ 
-\int_0^{\infty} u^5\left[1 - \dfrac{1}{1+e^{-u}} \right] du = \\
-\int_0^{\infty} u^5\left[ - \sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n e^{-nu} \right] du = \\
\sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n \int_0^{\infty} u^5 e^{-nu}  du = \\
\sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n \dfrac{120}{n^6} = \\
-\dfrac{31\pi^6}{252}
$$

Comment: That is correct.  Post the answer and I'll up vote.

Comment: The last equality comes from $\sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n n^{-k} = \zeta(k)\left(2^{1-k} - 1 \right)$ (like [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1169861)), and $\zeta(6) = \pi^6/945$, which is not an obvious result. But still this is a clever way! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Re(s)>0$ and
$$J(s)=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^sx}{1+x}dx.$$
Letting $x=e^{-u}$,
$$\begin{align}
J(s)&=(-1)^s\int_0^\infty\frac{u^se^{-u}}{1+e^{-u}}du\\
&=(-1)^s\int_0^\infty u^s\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^ne^{-nu}du\\
&=(-1)^s\sum_{n\ge1}(-1)^n\int_0^\infty u^se^{-nu}du\\
&=(-1)^s\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{s+1}}\int_0^\infty u^se^{-u}du\\
&=(-1)^s\Gamma(s+1)\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^{s+1}}\\
&=(-1)^s(2^{-s}-1)\Gamma(s+1)\zeta(s+1).
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}J&=\int_0^1 \frac{(\ln(x))^5}{1+x} \mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{(\ln(x))^5}{1-x} \mathrm{d}x-\int_0^1 \frac{2u(\ln(u))^5}{1-u^2} \mathrm{d}u\\
&\overset{x=u^2}=\int_0^1 \frac{(\ln(x))^5}{1-x} \mathrm{d}x-\frac{1}{2^5}\int_0^1 \frac{(\ln(x))^5}{1-x} \mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac{31}{32}\int_0^1 \frac{(\ln(x))^5}{1-x} \mathrm{d}x\\
&=-\frac{31}{32}\times \frac{5!}{945}\times \zeta(6)\\
&=\boxed{-\frac{31\pi^6}{252}}
\end{align}
I assume: $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{\ln^5 x}{1-x}dx=-5!\zeta(6)$ and $\displaystyle\zeta(6)=\frac{\pi^6}{945}$

Answer (score 0):

Use a geometric series.
$$\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kx^k$$
So
$$\mathcal{I}_n=\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)^n}{1+x}\mathrm{d}x=\sum_{m=0}^\infty\left[(-1)^mI_{m,n}\right]$$
Where
$$I_{m,n}=\int_0^1 x^m\ln(x)^n\mathrm{d}x$$
Now use a substitution $x=e^{-t}$ which changes our region of integration to $(\infty,0]$.
$$I_{m,n}=\int_\infty^0(e^{-t})^m(-t)^n(-e^{-t})\mathrm{d}t$$
$$=(-1)^n\int_0^\infty t^ne^{-t(m+1)}\mathrm{d}t$$
Now use another substitution $z=t(m+1)$:
$$I_{m,n}=(-1)^n\int_0^\infty\left(\frac{z}{m+1}\right)^ne^{-z}\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{m+1}$$
$$=\frac{(-1)^n ~n!}{(m+1)^{n+1}}$$
So then
$$\mathcal{I}_n=(-1)^nn!\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^m}{(m+1)^{n+1}}$$
$$=(-1)^nn!\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m^{n+1}}$$
$$=(-1)^n~n!~\eta(n+1)$$
Using the [Dirichlet eta function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletEtaFunction.html). In the case of $n=5$ we get
$$\mathcal{I}_5=-5!\cdot\eta(6)=\frac{-31\pi^6}{252}$$

Which is confirmed numerically by Mathematica:
[image: nintegrate]