# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^k x}{x+1}$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Evaluate:
> $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^k x}{x+1}$$

---

It looks like the only way to start this is to use that

$$\frac{1}{x+1}= \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^n $$

Then we have to evaluate

$$\int_{0}^{1} {\ln^k x}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^n = \int_{0}^{1} \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^n x^n{\ln^k x}=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1}(-1)^n x^n \ln^kx$$

---

For $k = 1$, it comes to be $\frac{\pi^2}{12}$

For $k = 3$, it comes to be $\frac{7\pi^4}{720}$

So, there is $\zeta(k+1)$ involved.

EDIT: After trying for different values of  $k$ it seems like the integral evaluates to be $(1 - \frac{1}{2^k}) \zeta(k+1)$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you justify the interversion $\sum$/$\int$ ?

Comment: Searching for dupes... right now I see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3890867).

Comment: hint: by the change $x=e^{-t}$ your integral becomes $({-1})^k\int_0^{\infty}\frac{t^k}{e^t+1}dt$

Comment: ... and a [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function) article on the subject.